# Javascript alert output in seq order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I have been asked in some interview what the output of the following code is:

```
function say(a) {
    alert(a);
}
say(1);
setTimeout(say(2), 5000);
setTimeout(function() {
    say(3);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(say, 2000, 4);
```

It's supposed to alert 1 2 3 4 but I don't know why in this order and I don't understand what the third argument in the last `setTimeout` function represents?

Answer (score 0):

> param1, ..., paramN Optional Additional parameters which are passed
>   through to the function specified by function or code once the timer
>   expires.
>   The 4 in the last call is passed to the say function as a parameter.

Comment: so why it alert last? and why this order or alert?

Comment: First alert is simply called without any delay.

Comment: The first parameter passed to the second call is not a function declaration but a function call, which is executed immediately.

Comment: Third is executed after 1 second (1000ms), fourth is after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument *schedules* the callback to run at some point in the future.

Your first call to `setTimeout(say(2), 5000)` is actually the same as the first call to `say(1)`, in that they both invoke the `say` function immediately. You need to pass a function like you did with the others.

So the first would be scheduled for 5 seconds out, but isn't because of the immediate invocation. The last two are scheduled for  1 second, then 2 seconds.

But because the `setTimeout` callbacks are run asynchronously, all the calls to `setTimeout` happen immediately, one after the other, without waiting for any of the callbacks.

The last call to `setTimeout` will print `4` because any arguments given after the *milliseconds* argument get forwarded to the callback, so your `4` value gets forwarded as the first argument to `say`.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter is argument of the function If a function is called with too many arguments (more than declared), these arguments can be reached using the arguments object. so that's why it's giving 4.
For more information try following function

```
setTimeout(say, 2000);
```

The above code will alert undefined It's because if a function is called with missing arguments (less than declared), the missing values are set to: undefined

Answer (score 0):

First of all it will alert **1**, then after 5 seconds it will alert **2**, then after 1 second it will alert **3**, and finally it will alert **4** after 2 seconds. settimeout means that you need to run a function after number of milliseconds. And since this function takes two arguments (The function you want to run, and the number of millieseconds); then in the 6th line, you say that you want to define a specific function, and inside this function you want to run **say** function (nested), and the value 1000 is the second argument of settimeout function.

Comment: That isn't how it works. The order of `setTimeout` called doesn't define the callback execution order.